# linux ldd command cannot work

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am using linux mint13 64bit

now ,when I use

```
ldd memcached
```

the error is below:

```
ldd: ./memcached: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Try `ldd \`which memcached\``

Comment: Try `ldd $(which memcached)` instead. And learn much more about `PATH`. The `ldd` command does work, but expects the file path of some executable... You could try `ldd /usr/bin/memcached` if your `memcached` is inside `/usr/bin/`

Comment: @Basile STARYNKEVITCH thanks mathk, I am now install memecahced, and i want to know which packages thant i need to install before i install memcahced, so I use ldd memcached, but it cannot work out. And when I use ldd 'other programme' is tell me that no such file or directory

Comment: If you install the `memcached` *package* (e.g. with `aptitude install memcached`) from your distribution, it will take care of *dependencies* as well. Managing packages dependencies is the job of the package manager of your distribution. If you want to build  `memcached` by yourself, you should care about the dependencies (e.g. with `aptitude build-dep memcached` etc....).

Comment: You should use the Mint Package Manager.. Don't try to apt-get them yourself

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I install memcached from source code, first i install libevent, and then i install memcached. but it tell me that i need to install libevent that i've installed before, so i use ldd command...

Comment: @OAOD install from source code

Comment: Do you have good reasons to avoid the `memcached` provided by your distribution? Then you still should `sudo aptitude build-dep memcached` at first before configuring and building your own `memcached`  (and that is a probable mistake for a newbie)..... And `ldd` does work (try `ldd /bin/ls` or `ldd /bin/sh` for example), it just needs the full file path....

Answer (score 0):

ldd search PATH if you don't use full(absolute path)

ldd could not find memcached because this command is not in search PATH
first of all find command location by find command , then use ldd

Comment: Wrong, `ldd` does not search `$PATH` (at least on Debian/Sid, with `ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38) 2.13` given by `ldd --version`). For instance `ldd sh` fails, while `/bin/sh` exists and `/bin` is in my `$PATH` (and the `ldd sh` command is being run from my `$HOME` directory which does not have any `sh` file).